# A "Feature Request"

Tags: feature-request

This is for the Moderators:  Would it be possible to place a comment (perhaps from the "Community Bot") to each "newbie" who asks a question here? The comment could have a few words of welcome, and a suggestion to read [this item in the rules.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any more access to Community bot than you do.

WRT helping people familiarise  themselves with the ins and outs of the place, the "New Contributor" label is something that was introduced not that long ago (a year or two?), and that's useful in identifying people who have not had that much of a chance to learn the ropes.

New users are explicitly asked to [take the Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) when they sign up, something I re-iterate in a first comment to a "New Contributor".  I wouldn't expect everyone to memorise everything there at a glance, but I think it goes a ways to at least make someone aware of the nature of the system WRT scores, voting, questions vs. answers, etc.

On the topic of "re-iterating to new users", I am too finicky for most of the template comments here so maintain my own set, accessed via a simple console app that lists them and accepts a list of corresponding numbers, eg. "1 2 3 5" is:

> Welcome -- **but this is not an answer to the question**, and no one will notice it *as a question* here. You can ask questions via the [Ask Question page](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), linked top right. You may include a link to this question if you think it is relevant. Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works. We have a fairly strict format that new users accustomed to "discussion style" forums sometimes find awkward.

That's injected into my clipboard so all I have to do then is paste it into the browser.  I know we are not all the sort of genius wizard capable of concocting such magic, but at a minimum, anyone could do almost as much by just copy-pasting from a file of quippy stuff.

The volume of posts by new users here is such that while having a Community bot available to do our bidding would be great, it seems unnecessary -- there's only been half a dozen new questions in the past 16 hours, so I think everything gets some eyeballs applied and cut pasting a comment as just described does not require much effort.

Also note that **if you answer a question and you believe the OP found it satisfactory** but didn't accept, it is okay to leave a comment such as

> If this answered your question, please indicate the solution for posterity by ticking the big checkmark on the left.

I actually don't have this one in my clip clip but I've done it enough times.